# Yield objects recursively in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have this list of json objects

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "ref": "id:2",
  "msg": "1"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "ref": "none",
  "msg": "2"
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "ref": "none",
  "msg": "3"
}
```

I want to be able (let's say search(id) is a function). if I call search(1) it needs to return the list of objects from (id=1) and all the ref objects that follow until one of the object has "ref": "none" or the `id` it references does not exist in the list of objects.

`"ref": "id:2",`, references the object with (id=2). I want to get all those objects until the `ref` field of one object is none or makes reference to a non-existing `id` in the list like "ref:101" (id=101 is not in the list)

Desired output for search(1)

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "ref": "id:2",
  "msg": "1"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "ref": "none",
  "msg": "2"
}
```

Comment: Is your input an array of objects (comma separated)? or just a newline separated list of objects.

Comment: Yes, we can consider the input as an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate your inputs into an object where you can easily navigate first. Then the rest is going to be plain recursion.

Like, with **-n/--null-input** specified, something like this should work just fine:

```
def prepare:
  reduce inputs as $in ({};
    . + ($in | {"id:\(.id)": .})
  );
def search($id):
  def follow($ref):
    if has($ref) then .[$ref], follow(.[$ref].ref) else empty end;
  follow("id:\($id)");
prepare | search(1)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iGuCUItL6w)</sup>

Comment: This approach works even if there are backreferences (i.e. if a node references a node found earlier in the input). A simpler solution exists if this feature isn't needed.

Comment: How about a version where we do not use -n/--null-input flag.

Comment: @SVCRVBRAND What's the difference? You'll have to slurp inputs anyway. https://jqplay.org/s/NpQnsOC_ua